# Angular 11 default TypeScript configuration: target 'es2015', lib 'es2018', but no polyfill?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

Bootstrapping a fresh Angular 11 app will generate the following `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    ... // Options not relevant for this question.
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
```

It also generates a `polyfills.ts` file with only `zone.js` enabled/uncommented.

My question is: Since we compile to `es2015`, but use `es2018` type definitions (e.g. `async iterables`, `promise.finally`, etc.), how can this be safe if no related polyfills are provided?
Why does the Angular 11 CLI not use `es2015` for `lib` as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular polyfills are automatically generated as `polyfills-es5.js`. In this file are the polyfills that angular internally needs to work. If your code uses features that are not part of what angular uses, you need to add this to the `polyfills.ts`.

Because the target is es2015, typescript will convert some es2018 features automatically, like the `async` stuff.

`es2015` is automatically included as lib, because it's a subset of `es2018` (i believe).

Sidenote:
If you were to use `es2018` as `target`, angular would give a warning on compilation, because the native `async/await` cannot be captured by zone.js. This is a non issue if you use `OnPush` everywhere

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I got it now! Angular would actually like to target `es2018`, but can't because of the capturing issue of `async-await`. So it instead targets `es2015` but still wants the programmer to use the other cool `es2018` features. In order to to so, it simply specifies `es2018` as `lib`, knowing that the intended runtime version (i.e. browser) will support those features. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @domin That is correct, but if you use features which are in es2018, which can not be transpiled by typescript to es2015, and which are not in use by the core angular framework, you need to include it in your `polyfills.ts`

Comment: I don‘t think so. If I use the ES2018 feature `Promise.prototype.finally`, I don‘t have to include any polyfills and my app still runs fine in modern browsers.

Comment: @domin something like that cannot be transpiled by typescript. `async/await` can. Modern browsers support `finally`, so obviously you don't need to include it in your polyfills :) Try running it on IE11, and I'm sure you'll have to add it

Comment: Isn‘t `Promise.finally` just a standard method call like any other and thus can be compiled by TS? Whether it exists at runtime is another question. It does in modern browser that support ES2018, but doesn‘t in IE11, which would require a polyfill, correct!

Comment: @domin because it's a standard method, transpiling won't happen. Transpiling happens with language features like `await/async` or optional chaining `?.`. Object methods are never transpiled for a certain target, and should be added to polyfills if your app should run on browsers that do not support it. I think that's the best explanation :D

Comment: I think we just don‘t agree on the term „transpiling“. If I write a program X purely in ES2015 syntax, it is valid TS, since TS is (syntactically) a superset of ES2015. If I run the TS compiler over X, I get out X unchanged. I would still say that X was transpiled to X. ;)

Comment: By the way: You say that the inability to patch native `async/await` by `zone.js` is a non-issue when using change detection strategy `onpush`. Why is that so? Angular still needs to find out if any input-references have changed. When does it do this check, however?

Comment: @domin those checks are done in the `@Input` decorator (I believe. at least that's how I would do it). The input is transformed to a setter and getter. And when it's set the component is marked as dirty

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! :) Thanks a lot for your answers!